# Use foldl reverses the list?

Tags: haskell

```
reverse'::[a] -> [a]
reverse' xs=foldl (\acc x -> x:acc) [] xs
example：
reverse' [1,2,3,4,5]
output:[5,4,3,2,1]
```

if I change the `acc` for `[]`

```
reverse' xs=foldl (\acc x -> x:[]) [] xs
```

it outputs

```
[5]
```

why?

Comment: Foldl will pass you a one. You put it in the start of the list. You get a two and put it at the start of the list. Now you have [2,1]. See where it is going?

Comment: Second case: First you get a one, prepend it to the empty list to get [1]. Then you get two, which you prepend to the empty list. You get [2]. See where this is going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foldl in Haskell works similarly to a for loop:

```
acc = []
for each x in xs:
    acc = (x:[])
return acc
```

Since the step you use to update `acc` doesn't depend on the previous value, the final result is only going to depend on the last element of the list (or will be the initial value of `acc`, if the list is empty).